# Set .Find range using row and column indexes

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am trying to set the range where I want to find specific strings of text to be the first and second row of the sheet and to search through all the columns until the last one with text is found. Right now I have it hard-coded to just look up until `Z2`, but there is a chance it could extend past column Z so I can't have it be hard-coded.
This is the line I am referring to.

```
Set paramname = sht.Range("A1:Z2").Find(What:=colname, Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=True)
```

I was thinking maybe I could try this

```
Set paramname = sht.Range("A1", sht.Cells(1, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlUp)).Cells.Find(What:=colname, Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=True)
```

Which does work if I only need to look in the first row, but I need to look in the second sometimes too depending on what `sht` is set to. So in that case it does not work entirely. If anyone has a suggestion as to how I can include row 2 into this please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could base this on `Sheets().UsedRange` to assess the last columns/row of the entire range, whereas you may have blanks in your target region, e.g.:

```
Debug.Print Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
Debug.Print Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count

dim lastCell as range:  set lastCell = Cells(Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count, Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count)
```

Using your code to just find the particular cell, you would want to update the row reference to "2":

```
'from:
sht.Cells(1, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlUp)
'to:
sht.Cells(2, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlUp)
```

Comment: Is there a way to refer to the first cell `A1` without calling it exactly in that position. Like what if all the data didnt start until `A3`, is there a way to say start in the first cell with data for column A?

Comment: @resu_student think of it like playing battle ship... you have to know where something is to affect it; you would reference `A1` directly, or you could find the first cell with data via `find`/etc... there are lots of ways, but that rabbit hole is outside of the scope of this post.  Did this response help you resolve your issue?